# SVN update fetch all new directories in top level

Tags: svn, version-control

I have a top level directory **X** which is my working copy root path. In this I have multiple directories `a`, `b` and `c`.

Now suppose directories `d` and `e` are added by some one else, How do I get them using `svn up`.

I don't want to do `svn up . --depth=infinity` as this brings unnessary branches in the sub directories or `svn co d and e` as I am not always aware what are all the newly added sub directories.

Do I have to use `svn ls` to see the new ones and checkout them one by one or is there any better option?

Edit: I have tried `svn co <remote> . --depth=immediates`. But this changed the existing directories to only have immediates and fetched the new ones.